# JSLint Missing Semi-colon

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, jslint

I got that error message but I'm not sure where a semi-colon should be.  This is the code.

```
$('.animation1').delay(350).queue(function(){
    $(this).addClass("animate-from-top")
});
```

Comment: Note that correctly formatting your code (as I've edited for you) makes issues like this much easier to find.

Comment: Interestingly enough semi colons are optional in Javascript, making your code correct. However, Douglas Crockford, who created json and jslint amongst many other things thinks this is bad, and he's probably correct :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the callback, after the function `addClass()` the semicolon is missing:

```
$('.animation1').delay(350)
                .queue(function(){
                   $(this).addClass("animate-from-top");
// semicolon missing here -----------------------------^ 
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

like this

```
$('.animation1').delay(350).queue(function(){$(this).addClass("animate-from-top");});
```